# Android get 4 random numbers

Tags: java, android, while-loop

I need to get numbers 1-4 randomly and store it in an arrayList.  I have a good start, but I may have an infinite loop because the emulator keeps crashing.  The numbers can also not be used more than once.

```
** lightSelector is a global variable (int lightSelector = 1;)
** generatedOrder is my ArrayList

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
        lightSelector = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 4);           
        generatedOrder.add(lightSelector);
        boolean contains = true;
        System.out.print(generatedOrder.get(i));
        if (!generatedOrder.isEmpty())
        {
            // Loop until a number is generated that hasn't already been picked
            while (contains) 
            {
                if (generatedOrder.contains(lightSelector))
                    lightSelector = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 4);
                else
                {
                    generatedOrder.add(lightSelector);
                    contains = false;
                    break;
                }       
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You'll get a logcat output if it crashes. What does that say?

Comment: error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Comment: It'll be longer. About 10-30 lines. In red or yellow. Edit it into your question

Comment: If I select the error dropdown in LogCat (I'm using Eclipse) it's only that one error.  The rest of the text is blue/green.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more efficient way to get four numbers in a randomly sorted order is to do the following algorithm:

1) Create an int[] array such as {1, 2, 3, 4};

2) For i = 0; i < array.length; ++i, generate a random number, j, between i and array.length-1 **inclusive** and swap i and j.

Important: That means the possible swaps would be one of 00,01,02,03 followed by one of 11,12,13 followed by one of 22,23 followed by one of 33. This gives you all 4*3*2*1 = 4! ways to permute an array, and that's required for the algorithm to be correct.

(If, for example, you had 4^4 = 256 possible ways for the algorithm to complete, 24 doesn't go into 256 evenly and so some shuffles would be more likely to appear than others.)

This shuffling algorithm has a name: [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)

EDIT: A good way to generate random numbers in an integer range is to do the following:

1) Generate `Random rng = new Random()`; exactly once. Don't make a new one ever, because if you make two Random instances in the same time they give exactly the same random number streams.

2) Random has a method, `nextInt(n)` that returns a random int between 0 and n - 1, so to get random numbers between i and j inclusive do `nextInt(j+1-i)+i`. To get random numbers between i and j but excluding j, do `nextInt(j-i)+i`.

API reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Comment: To generate the random number j, should I use the same logic I did for the lightSelector except change the max/min value?

Comment: @Andrew I edited into my answer the way I would prefer to do it.

Comment: @Andrew Good luck! Always read documentation and never forget to debug code that isn't doing what you think it is ;)